# Can't Use Unknown Input Dims (Batch Size) When Making Custom Keras Layer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am attempting to build a custom layer in Keras (backend TensorFlow) that performs KMeans Clustering across the filters of a Convolutional Layer. In building the logic for this layer, I iterate across the batch size, but it does not seem that Keras/TensorFlow are allowing this to happen, as the batch size is an unknown dimension until runtime.

I have attempted to trace through the error messages, and it leads me to two files: keras/engine/training.py and keras/engine/training_utils.py, and from what I can tell, the error stems from a problem with a `ndim` variable that gets defined to `NoneType`, as there is no known batch size when the model is compiled.

In looking through various StackOverflow and GitHub resources, I have not seen any solution for how to handle Keras/TensorFlow rejecting an unknown batch size argument.

For reference, here is the sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

class KMeansLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, clusters=8, n_init=5, trainable=False, **kwargs):
        super(KMeansLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.clusters = clusters
        self.n_init = n_init

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.output_s = (input_shape[0],input_shape[1], input_shape[2],1)
        self.depth = input_shape[3]
        self.built=True

    def call(self, inputs):

        def KMeansFunc(input_tens,clusters=self.clusters,n_init=self.n_init):
            base_mat = np.zeros((input_tens.shape[0],input_tens.shape[1],input_tens.shape[2]))

            for frame in range(input_tens.shape[0]):
                init_mat = np.zeros((input_tens.shape[1]*input_tens.shape[2]))
                # print(init_mat.shape)
                reshape_mat = np.reshape(input_tens[frame],(input_tens.shape[1]*input_tens.shape[2],input_tens.shape[3]))
                # print(reshape_mat.shape)
                kmeans_init = KMeans(n_clusters=clusters, n_init=n_init)
                class_pred = kmeans_init.fit_predict(reshape_mat)

                for clust in range(self.clusters):
                    init_mat[class_pred==clust] = np.mean(reshape_mat[class_pred==clust],axis=1)
                    init_mat[class_pred==clust] = np.mean(reshape_mat[class_pred==clust],None)
                # print(base_mat.shape)

                base_mat[frame]=np.reshape(init_mat,(input_tens.shape[1],input_tens.shape[2]))

            return np.expand_dims(base_mat,axis=-1).astype('float32')

            
        output = tf.py_func(KMeansFunc,[inputs],tf.float32) 
        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return self.output_s


input_1 = keras.Input(shape=(28,28,1), name='input_1', dtype='float32')

conv_1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=20, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', data_format='channels_last', activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(input_1)
pool_1 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding='same', data_format='channels_last')(conv_1)

up_conv_1 = keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters=20, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding='same', data_format='channels_last', activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(pool_1)
up_1 = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation='bilinear')(up_conv_1)
conv_2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=20, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', data_format='channels_last', activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(up_1)

conv_3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', data_format='channels_last', activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(conv_2)

kmeans_out = KMeansLayer(clusters=8,n_init=5)(conv_3)


model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_1], outputs=kmeans_out)
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
```

As can be seen in the above code, if I have an input into my custom layer of size `(batch_size,28,28,3)`, I expect to create output of size `(batch_size,28,28,1)`.

The error that I get as a result of running the above code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_error_file.py", line 64, in <module>
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
  File "~/fenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 347, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "~/fenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 426, in weighted
    axis=list(range(weight_ndim, ndim)))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I have two main questions:

- Is there something I am doing incorrectly when defining my custom Keras Layer?
- Is there any way to force Keras to operate without knowing the batch size in this instance (which seems reasonable)?

TensorFlow Version: 1.7.0
Keras Version: 2.2.4
Python: 3.6.6

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that event if we were to just look at this in entirely tensorflow, since the shape isn't known until runtime, when tensorflow tried to compile this graph its gonna get some errors with the whole looping through None.

Instead of using tf.pyfunc consider using tf.function or autograph (if you're on tensorflow version 1.14.0 or greater).

Alternatively you could use tf.scan which would apply a function to each element in a tensor, where each element is made up of each tensor that is unpacked from the original tensor at dimension 0.

Either should work!